# Databricks: Cannot access mounted blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, mount-point, dbutils

I mounted a blob storage container (confirmed blob type):

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://mycontainer@myblobstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/mymountpoint",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.mycontainer.myblobstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "mydatabricksscope", key = "nameofmysecretinkeyvault")})
```

The mount point is created and I can see it in databricks. I placed a csv file in this container as well as a file that contains further csv files but cannot access anything:

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/mymountpoint/")
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: / is not found

```
dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://mycontainer@mystorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/")
```

shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container ownbackupsalesforcedevemastercnt in account ownbackupsalesforcedev.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.

```
df = spark.read.format('csv').load('/mnt/mymountpoint/mycsv.csv', header="true")
```

AnalysisException: Path does not exist: dbfs:/mnt/ownbackupsalesforcemnt/accounts.csv

I've redone the secret scope in databricks and unmounted and remounted this several times but still cannot get in. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: can you mount it within  try-except  block, to see whether it returns any error during mounting.  try:  except Exception as e: print(e)

Answer (score 1):

First try this without the secret scope.

Please follow below process:

- As you are trying to mount using **SAS**(Shared access Signature), go to storage and click on Shared access signature in the sidebar. 
  Please make sure you check the **Service**, **Container**, **Object** in Allowed resource type.

[image]

- Now click on Generate SAS and copy it and paste in the your code.

  `dbutils.fs.mount( source = "wasbs://mycontainer@myblobstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net", mount_point = "/mnt/mymountpoint", extra_configs =  {"fs.azure.sas.mycontainer.myblobstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net":  "SAS")})`
- Please make sure you **remove ? character in the SAS** before adding it to the code.

Please check these outputs as per my repro:

[image]

[image]

Also, instead you can try with the **account key** in storage account to mount.

[image]

Syntax:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(source = "wasbs://<containername>@<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net",
                 mount_point = "/mnt/<mountname>",
                 extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.<container name>.<account name>.blob.core.windows.net': ‘account key’}
)
```

In case if you still face same issue after using it with secret scope, may be the issue is with the Secret scope.

Please refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes) to learn about the Secret scope.

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#mount-azure-blob

Comment: I tried this approach and unfortunately it does not work.
It also differs from what is reported in the linked documentation.